# If I visit Moldova on an ID card, how can the police see I'm legally in the country?

Tags: overstaying, officials, moldova, eu-id-card

As a Swedish national, I'm allowed to visit Moldova without a residence permit for 3 months in a 6-month period.

When going there I use my ID Card (accepted since September 2014), which cannot be stamped.

I've lately been asking myself: if I'm ever stopped for a police check, how can officers see that I've legally entered Moldova and not overstayed?

Comment: Do they scan your card when you enter?

Comment: @phoog Not always actually. At the Ungheni train border they take it out for an hour (whilst the train is changing bogies), and at Chisinau airport they scan it, but the one time I entered by minibus at Husi (the main crossing from Romania), they literally looked at the front and back for 2 seconds each to see the issuing country, and then waved me through. Just like when entering/exiting Serbia by train (specifically), although I suppose that one's compensated for by the mandatory police registration (not that they ever ask for them)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Moldova Border Police website](http://www.border.gov.md/index.php/en/public-information/faq):

> Foreign citizens and stateless persons arriving in Moldova **are
>   recorded** when crossing the state border **and their identification data
>   is introduced in the Population State Register**.

So they will have the information in their system when you entered the country, and thus the officers have a way to check whether you entered Moldova legally and did not overstay.

If you're really concerned, you can carry the boarding pass with you, but I'd say there is no need really. Moldova is not a place with a large number of overstays, so if they suspect you did, they'd probably be really curious.

The only time it may be a concern is if you enter Moldova from Ukraine (via Transdnister region). In this case you will not go through the Moldova border control, and thus would have to register your data as following (same link):

> Foreign citizens and stateless persons entering the Republic of
>   Moldova through the Moldova-Ukraine border sector which is not under
>   control of Moldovan authorities, are obliged to inform  within 72
>   hours on their arrival at any population evidence and documentation
>   unit (division) of the Ministry of Information Technologies and
>   Communications. It is necessary to present the national identification
>   document allowing entry in Moldova.